# rsync chmod and chown operation not permitted

Tags: filesystems, rsync, backup

I am trying to backup my filesystem to my SSD so I can boot from SSD.  The issue I am having is RSYNC is giving me errors.  I am running

```
sudo rsync -aAXv / --exclude=/media/* --exclude=/mnt/* /mnt/mydrive
```

which should carry over permissions and groups.  I don't want to mess anything up once I have my ssd ready so I want to preserve all groups and settings.  I have a bunch of programs running on here. plex,sonarr,radar.

The destination folder is mounted as root.  I am running rsync as root.  What am I missing here?

---

From comments:

What file system is on `/mnt/mydrive` is the question? It's FAT32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What file system is on `/mnt/mydrive` is the question? It's FAT32.

FAT32 file system can't hold Unix ownership and permissions. You need some Unix file system like Ext4 for example.